# How to create a dialog with custom buttons that can close itself in AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to pop up a simple dialog modal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops that doesn't include default buttons (by setting buttons: null in the dialog options).

How do I go about creating my own buttons that will be able to close the modal?

Comment: Hi, Were the okText and cancelText attributes mentioned in below answer what your were looking for.  How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **okText** and **cancelText** attributes to specify your own titles for the OK and Cancel buttons. See below example:

```
 var dialogOptions = {
        title: "My Dialog Title",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        okText: "Yes",
        cancelText: "No" 
    };
```

In above example, i set the **okText** to **Yes** and **cancelText** to "**No**". 
Then it will show the OK button and Cancel button as below:

[image]

See [Customizing the dialog buttons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/using-host-dialog?view=azure-devops#customizing-the-dialog-buttons) for more information.